# How to solve the following recurence relation

Tags: math, discrete-mathematics, recurrence

How do I solve the following recurrence relation?

```
f(n+2) = 2*f(n+1) - f(n) + 2  where n is even
f(n+2) = 3*f(n)               where n is odd
f(1) = f(2) = 1
```

For odd `n` I could solve the recurrence and it turns out to be a geometric series with common ratio 3.

When `n` is even I could find and solve the homogeneous part of the recurrence relation by substituting `f(n) = r^n`. So the solution comes to be `r = 1`. Therefore the solution is `c1 + c2*n`. But how do I solve the particular integral part? Am I on the right track? Are there any other approaches to the above solution?

Comment: You need another boundary condition because you have two coefficients in the particular integral, e.g. what is the value of `f(3)`?

Comment: the value of f(3) or any odd number is computed by the other recurrence relation f(n+2) = 3 * f(n) where n is odd and f(1) = 1. Therefore f(3) = 3.

Comment: `r^n` is a correct starting point but you must always make your substitution form as **general** as possible - especially if there are terms which don't depend on the input parameter (`+ 2`).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about mathematics instead of directly about programming / coding / programming tools / software algorithms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recurrence for **odd** `n` is very easy to solve with the substitution you tried:

[image]

Substituting this into the recurrence for **even** `n`:

[image]

---

**Attempt #1**

Make a general substitution of the form:

[image]

<sup>Note that the exponent is `n/2` instead of `n` based on the odd recurrence, but it is purely a matter of choice</sup>

[image]

Matching the same types of terms:

[image]

But this solution doesn't work with the boundary condition `f(2) = 1`:

[image]

---

**Attempt #2**

It turns out that a *second exponential term* is required:

[image]

[image]

As before, one of the exponential terms needs to match `3^(n/2)`:

[image]

The last equation has solutions `d = 0, -1`; obviously only the non-trivial one 
 is useful:

[image]

The final solution for **all** `n ≥ 2`:

> [image]

---

**Alternative method**

Longer but (possibly, at least I found it to be) more intuitive - expand the recurrence `m` times:

[image]

Observe the pattern:

1. The additive factor of  2 is present for *odd* number of expansions `m` but cancels out for *even* `m`.
2. Each expansion *adds* a factor of `2 * 3^(n/2-m)` for *odd* `m`, and *subtracts* it for *even* `m`.
3. Each expansion also *adds* a factor of `f(n-2m)` for *even* `m`, and *subtracts* it for *odd* `m`.

Combining these observations to write a general closed form expression for the `m`-th expansion:

[image]

Using the standard formula for geometric series in the last step.

Recursion stops at `f(2) = 1`:

[image]

The same result as before.